# Scatter plot Matplotlib 2D > 3D

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i have this working code for scatter animation in 2D:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
def _update_plot(i, fig, scat):
    scat.set_offsets(([0, i], [50, i], [100, i]))
    return scat,
fig = plt.figure()
x = [0, 50, 100]
y = [0, 0, 0]
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([-50, 200])
ax.set_ylim([-50, 200])
scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c=x)
scat.set_alpha(0.8)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs=(fig, scat), frames=100, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

I tried to convert it into 3D with this but it wont work..

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def _update_plot(i, fig, scat):
    scat._offsets3d([0, 0, 0], [50, 0, 0], [100, 0, 0])

    return scat

fig = plt.figure()

x = [0, 50, 100]
y = [0, 0, 0]
z = [0, 0, 0]

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

scat = ax.scatter(x, y, z)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs=(fig, scat), frames=100, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

Can someone please give me an advice on how to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`_offsets3d` is an attribute, not a method. Instead of

```
scat._offsets3d([0, 0, 0], [50, 0, 0], [100, 0, 0])
```

you will need to assign the tuple of `(x,y,z)` values to it:

```
scat._offsets3d = ([0, 0, 0], [50, 0, 0], [100, 0, 0])
```

This will of course always produce the same plot for all 100 frames. So in order to see an animation something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def _update_plot(i, fig, scat):
    scat._offsets3d = ([0, i, i], [50, i, 0], [100, 0, i])
    return scat

fig = plt.figure()

x = [0, 50, 100]
y = [0, 0, 0]
z = [0, 0, 0]

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

scat = ax.scatter(x, y, z)

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.set_zlim(0,100)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs=(fig, scat), frames=100, interval=100)

plt.show()
```